# Publish flutter module aar via jitpack

Tags: android, flutter, maven, aar, jitpack

right now im working on making flutter plugin/module for my client to integrate the function for cross-platform mobile development, Ive finished my library plugin (as flutter module)   and then I've made a new native android project and import the flutter engine and my plugin on it and test it, after that I build .aar file to publish to jitpack maven.

[image: However i found that there are 2 aar output, one is in flutter (flutter engine) module and other in my flutter library plugin output, i build the aar using gradle release command.]

I prepared the jitpack.yml as well as pom.xml so that jitpack/maven can compile my code (the same method like we push our aar from android native module).
I've released via github and published my flutter library plugin to maven via jitpack and imported it into a new android project, and when i try my library function, it got error like it is can't load the flutter engine.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tp.myapplication, PID: 30463
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/flutter/embedding/engine/loader/FlutterLoader;
        at com.tp.tptaq_bms_util_sdk_android.Sdk.<init>(Sdk.kt:24)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-2(MainActivity.kt:48)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$p-T2ovqciOBI8oz2XMMTW0zjQmU(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7185)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7162)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:819)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27678)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tp.myapplication-pJtqkn5L82xvyBriZuwfRg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tp.myapplication-pJtqkn5L82xvyBriZuwfRg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:230)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.tp.tptaq_bms_util_sdk_android.Sdk.<init>(Sdk.kt:24) 
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-2(MainActivity.kt:48) 
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$p-T2ovqciOBI8oz2XMMTW0zjQmU(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onClick(Unknown Source:2) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7185) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7162) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:819) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27678) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I wonder if we also need to publish the flutter engine, but I still don't know how to compile it together as one aar, does anyone have experience on this? Any suggestions will help me a lot, Thank you in advance :)

My sample code as reference : [text](https://github.com/farhantandia/tptaq_bms_sdk_android)

Ive published the aar successfuly but the function is getting error, I need to know how to solve this issue?